# Struggling to run a collection with specified environment via Newman

Tags: postman, newman

Pre condition:
I have Newman installed.
My collection and environment .json files work fine in postman

Problem
When I run this command "newman run  collection.json –e env.json" via powershell on my local machine or via CI using the "postman/newman_alpine33" docker.

I get this error:

```
  POST {{baseUrl}}/api/student/create [errored]
     getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{baseurl}}
```

The {{baseURL}} is referring to environment variable in the env.json that should be used in the collection.json.

Take note: I have tried this with other terminals as well and problems still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: There was an extra space between run and collection.json, when I removed the space then it worked. Must be  like this: `"newman run collection.json –e env.json"`
and NOT like this`"newman run  collection.json –e env.json"`

Answer (score 1):

also, make sure your values are stored in initial and current

Comment: at least for me, that was the issue :D 
Thankyou @Laser Hawk